# Submitting multiple forms with one submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In my photo portfolio admin page, I've built a tool to caption, keyword and credit each photo. Until now, I've dynamically listed multiple forms, each containing a submit button. With 20+ photos/forms on the page, this can be a boring job and was hoping to build on this by adding a button at the bottom of the page to submit all.

I went ahead and built what I thought was a good approach and looped through all the forms one-by-one and posted the data to a PHP page using AJAX. This worked fine, but like I mentioned, with 20+ photos, it's running 20 AJAX requests and 20 SQL updates, and now feel this is a poor effort.

I'm now looking at other ways that involve looping through each form, creating an array or object, and sending it in one request and have one nifty SQL query to update all rows at once.

This is where I'm at now. I'm struggling to get the form fields into a readable and usable object for my PHP to read.

**MY FORM STRUCTURE**

```
<form name="12344">
    <div class="input_wrap">
        <textarea id="12344_caption"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="input_wrap">
        <input type="text" id="12344_keywords" />
    </div>
    <div class="input_wrap">
        <input type="text" id="12344_credit" />
    </div>
    <div class="input_wrap">
        <input type="text" id="12344_credit_url" />
    </div>
</form>

<form name="12345">
    <div class="input_wrap">
        <textarea id="12345_caption"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="input_wrap">
        <input type="text" id="12345_keywords" />
    </div>
    <div class="input_wrap">
        <input type="text" id="12345_credit" />
    </div>
    <div class="input_wrap">
        <input type="text" id="12345_credit_url" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**MY JQUERY SO FAR**

```
var photo_annotations = {};

$('form').each(function(i) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var caption = $('#'+id+'_caption').val();
    var keywords = $('#'+id+'_keywords').val();
    var credit = $('#'+id+'_credit').val();
    var credit_url = $('#'+id+'_credit_url').val();

    // create object to post
    photo_annotations[id].push({});
    (help)

}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax/save-annotations.php',
    data: { json: JSON.stringify(photo_annotations) }
});
```

This is the kind of data I'd like to construct:

```
photo_annotations = {
    "12344": {
        "caption": "This is a caption for the photo ID 12344.",
        "keywords": "Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3",
        "credit": "John Doe",
        "credit_url": "http://www.johndoe.com"
    },
    "12345": {
        "caption": "This is a caption for the photo ID 12345.",
        "keywords": "Keyword4, Keyword5, Keyword6",
        "credit": "Joe Bloggs",
        "credit_url": "http://www.joebloggs.com"
    }   
}
```

I'm struggling to get my form fields into JSON correctly, in the format I showed you above. I hope that somebody could show me how to achieve this format.

Comment: Why don't you just wrap it all in a single form tag? Or you could just pass `$('form').serialize()`

Comment: @Rob: Because I'd like to keep both the 'submit individually' and 'submit all' features.

Comment: You can have multiple submit buttons in a single form, each with a different name, and just check which submit button was clicked server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need push or separate variables.  You can just build it directly like this:

```
photo_annotations[id] = {
  id: $(this).attr('id'),
  caption: $('#'+id+'_caption').val(),
  keywords: $('#'+id+'_keywords').val(),
  credit: $('#'+id+'_credit').val(),
  credit_url: $('#'+id+'_credit_url').val()
}
```

Comment: Perfect, and so simple too. I really must play with objects more often and I may not look so silly asking simple questions. I had to move the top ID field outside of the object, as photo_annotations[id] needs the ID value. Welcome to StackOverflow by the way.

Comment: Right, missed that one.  Since you need the id to key the index as well as fetch the rest of the values.

Answer (score 2):

```
photo_annotations[id] = {
    caption: caption
    /* and so on */
};
```